# SKU codes problems while uploading bulk products

Tags: sku, upload, bulk

I am having problem while uploading bulk products.

Let suppose I am uploading 3 products having `SKU` following:

> SFP-10G-AOC1.5M-AO
>
> SFP-10G-AOC1-5M-AO
>
> SFP-10G-AOC1/5M-AO

While uploading my slugify function convert the first `SKU` to `SFP-10G-AOC1-5M-AO`, second to `SFP-10G-AOC1-5M-AO` and third to `SFP-10G-AOC1-5M-AO`.

At the end i am having error of same `SKU`. Can it handle in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

A stock-keeping unit (SKU) is an alphanumeric code that identifies a product and helps you track inventory for your retail business. You can create SKU numbers manually or using inventory management or point-of-sale (POS) software.

SKU numbers are **unique** to each store and allow the store to keep track of each item in inventory. SKU numbers can be anything you want to be but are most often about 8 alpha-numeric digits

try with different skus

or add as it is and change it after uploading